# Why would Principal Vagina interpret "moon stuff" that way?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, rick-and-morty

In *Morty's MindBlower* (*Rick and Morty* S3E8), when Morty told Principal Vagina that Mr. Lunas was "up to something" and "lives on the moon", Principal Vagina thought "lives on the moon" was a hint that Mr. Lunas was a pedophile. This could be seen from the conversation between him and Morty after he confronted Mr. Lunas and punched him in the face:

> M: What did he say?
>
> P: Denied the moon stuff, but that's what pedophiles do, they deny, it's their bread and butter.
>
> M: Pedophile?
>
> P: You don't think so? I thought the moon thing might have been code.
>
> M: No, he's literally from the moon!
>
> P: Well, you saw him react. Moon or not, that dude likes 'em young.

My question is, why would Principal Vagina take the moon stuff as "code" for pedophilia? There is absolutely no connection between the two as I can see.

Comment: You may want to remove "pedophilia" from the title to not spoil users.

Comment: @Larme sorry. I didn't realise that.

Comment: Imagine if, during World War II, a guy in a trench coat comes and sits next to you on a park bench. Without looking at you, he leans in and says "the chicken is in Picadilly Circus". Obviously, you would assume that he's using some kind of code and not being literal. Principal Vagina made the same assumption that Morty is using code; but then also inferred that it was about pedophilia (because what else would you be hesitant about in a school context when talking about a creepy looking teacher?)

Comment: I think that's part of the joke, maybe? She's really clueless and basically invents and believes some kind of secret, insightful, expert knowledge that isn't anything of the sort, and then becomes locked in and invested in it.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet whos "she"?

Comment: At Vim - sorry, I'm not familiar with the show. With the name of the principal, I assumed female.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Principal Vagina was just really confused.

You can tell he is trying to make sense of what Morty is saying.  A student telling you he's "up to something" and "from the moon" doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Morty was very convinced that something was wrong though, so he was very worried.  Obviously a good principal would be worried if his students were.

Principal Vagina isn't the most *aware* person though.  He knows something is wrong;  and makes an *assuption* which isn't a very good one.  This leads to a confrontation under a false premise.

He's just assuming his student was molested bit doesn't know how to say it.  Morty was talking literally though, which doesn't make much sense from the principals perspective.

Answer (score -3):

Well, to moon someone means to show your exposed butt to someone.  And what does it mean to "live on it"?  Well it means you spend a lot of time there.  So one way to interpret it is that "lives on the moon" means he likes to be around the butt.  why would someone be around that area?  possibly sexual stuff.  Now as for how the principal jumped to pedophila, it could be that Mr lunes chose to pick a profession where he could be close to children.  Men have to be more careful about being close (distance-wise) to children.  there have been cases where a Man was trying to help a young girl find her father.  But the father say the man with his daughter and assumed he was a pedo and beat the shit out of him.

Comment: This makes no sense.